# Dropbutton in Twig

Tags: 8, theming

I'm adding a few links to a views twig template file and I would like to render them as a dropbutton. For example ...

[image]

Is this at all possible ... to render this in twig? If this were a form, I understand how I could define it, but it's just a straight collection of links. I'm sure I could locate some other CSS and JS to make this work, but would love for it to just keep the consistent look if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build and manipulate render arrays inside a Twig template, and then render them with the `render_var()` function or the `|render` filter: https://www.drupal.org/node/2448219

As [dropbutton is a render element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21Dropbutton.php/class/Dropbutton/8.5.x) this means you can define it in Twig just as you would in a form, and then directly render it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I've used Twig with Symfony before but am a little new to D8 theming. Took me a minute to figure out it was best (only possible?) to create the render array in a preprocess function, but once I set a var to that array, Twig rendered it perfectly!